# Laravel Many to many filter by pivot attributes

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many, relation

I have 2 tables and a pivot table with extra attributes

table cars

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW |
| 2 | Mercedes |
| 3 | Bugatti |

table status

| id | colors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 3 | green |

car_color pivot

| car_id | color_id | is_stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

this is my relations

```
    //  Car model
    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class)->withPivot('is_stock');;
    }

    //  Color model
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class)->withPivot('is_stock');;
    }
```

I want get `list of Red BMWs where is_stocks = 1`
i do it with mysql query like this

```
    $red_bmw_stocks = DB::table('car_color')->where('is_stocks ', '1');
```

how can i convert it to eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cars = Car::with('colors')->wherePivot('is_stock', 1);
```

Comment: it returns the word 'pivot' instead of the actual table

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use wherePivot

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class)->wherePivot('is_stock', 1);
```

according to this doc , from laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns